# In Ruby, why is my base class only being puts once?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I'd appreciate knowing why the instance of `"Cat"` below isn't also putting the `"This animal can:"` text before its specific instance attributes. I'm expecting an output like this:

```
This animal can:
Say it's name: 'Rover'
Bark
This animal can:
Say its name: 'Satan'
Meow
```

Here's the code:

```
class Animal
    puts "This animal can:"
end

class Dog < Animal
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        puts "Say its @name: '%s'" % [name]
    end
    def bark
        puts "Bark"
    end
end

class Cat < Animal
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        puts "Say its @name: '%s'" % [name]
    end
    def meow
        puts "Meow"
    end
end

rover = Dog.new("Rover").bark
satan = Cat.new("Satan").meow
```

What I'm seeing is this:

```
This animal can:
Say it's name: 'Rover'
Bark
Say its name: 'Satan'
Meow
```

Doesn't `"cat"` also inherit from the `Animal` class? Shouldn't its output also begin with `"This animal can:"`?

Comment: Ideally the puts "This animal can:" will not be printed for both. is this your complete code? which version of ruby you use?

Comment: Yes, that's my complete code (exercise from Learn Ruby the Hard Way). Unfortunately, I'm only on Ruby 1.8.7 (stupid work thing).

Comment: Does your work allow you to install to your home directory? Try out RVM for installing self-contained rubies. https://rvm.io/

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your code is that:

```
puts "This animal can:"
```

is run when the Animal class gets defined. It seems like you want this in the initializer:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(name)
    puts "This animal can:"
  end
end
```

You'll then need to call `super` in the other initializers for the result you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, so the class is only defined once. Makes sense to me. But I'm creating two new instances of it. Don't those new instances inherit the traits of the base class?

Comment: They inherit the methods, etc. But the code that defines the actual class is only run (as in interpreted/compiled...) once.

Answer (score 2):

The "This Animal can:" line only occurs when the class is defined, since it doesn't live in a method. Since both animals have common behavior in their initializers, you might want to promote the initializer to the Animal class.

```
class Animal
  def introduce_myself
    puts "Hello! My name is #{@name} and I know how to: "
  end

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    introduce_myself
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  def bark
    puts "Woof!"
  end
end

class Cat < Animal
  def meow
    puts "Meow!"
  end
end

Dog.new("Fido").bark
Cat.new("Sparky").meow
```

Output:

```
Hello! My name is Fido and I know how to: 
Woof!
Hello! My name is Sparky and I know how to: 
Meow!
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, promoting the initializer makes more sense. Ruby's Don't repeat yourself philosophy. Ok, working on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Animal class doesn't define a constructor, nor is it called by inheritors:

```
class Animal
   def initialize
      puts "This animal can:"
   end
end

class Dog < Animal    
   def initialize(name)
       super()
       @name = name
       puts "Say its @name: '%s'" % [name]
   end

   def bark
       puts "Bark"
   end    
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Is "constructor" the same as method/function?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)): A constructor resembles an instance method, but it differs from a method in that it has no explicit return type, it is not implicitly inherited and it usually has different rules for scope modifiers.

There is a lot more there for you to read about constructors.

Comment: I meant initializer, yes it's considered a regular method in ruby (almost).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly!

```
class Animal
  def initialize(name)
    puts "This animal can:"
  end
end

def initialize(name)
  @name = name
  puts "Say its @name: '%s'" % [name]
  super # initializer from parent class
end
```

why that don't work ?

```
class Animal
  puts "This animal can:"
end
```

when ruby parser read code it evaluate everything on way. I mean even if you will not create any object it will display "This animal can:" That's why you saw that for the first time and had impression that Dog class worked correctly

Answer (score -1):

Install `name_magic` (`gem install y_support`) and have fun

```
require 'y_support/name_magic';     

class Animal
  include NameMagic
  def initialize; puts "This animal #{sound}s." end
  def sound; "growl" end
  def speak; puts "#{sound.capitalize}!" end
end

class Dog < Animal
  def sound; "bark" end
end

class Cat < Animal
  def sound; "meow" end
end

def hullo( animal )
  Animal.instance( animal ).speak
end

Rover = Dog.new
#=> This animal barks.
Satan = Cat.new
#=> This animal meows.

hullo :Rover
#=> Bark!

Animal.instances.each( &:speak )
#=> Bark!
#=> Meow!
```

Comment: Are you aware of `nokogiri` sir? If so then I will ask some questions to you. Please confirm if you have no problem. :)

Comment: I am aware of `nokogiri`'s existence as an XML parser. However, I have never used it. I am actively avoiding XML as a data format in my work, preferring Ruby internal DSL. Apart from that, I have no problems talking about anything.